# DIV overflow:auto percentage width using content and not parent to set width

Tags: css, width

I have a `DIV`, such as below, and the following classes applied to them. I want the wrapper `DIV` to scroll when necessary and to fit 100% of the screen width. The problem I'm seeing is that the wrapper `DIV`, when I set it to `width: 100%` is using the width of the contents and not the parent.

The wrapper DIV in question is `#pageContent_headingsWrapper`. On a smartphone's small viewport, the `width: 100%` is expanding outside of the screen and making the page very large. I don't know why.

Any ideas?

Also, I want a horizontal row of boxes in pageContent_headings. In order to get inline-block elements to be in a single horizontal line, I have to set the width of pageContent_headings to something like 800 pixels, which then makes pageContent_headingsWrapper become that same width, instead of the parent.

```
<div id="pageContentWrapper" class="default">
    <div id="pageContentWrapperCell">
        <div id="pageContent_headingsWrapper">
            <div id="pageContent_headings"></div>
        </div>
    <div id="pageContent_content"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS for large viewport:**

```
#pageContentWrapper.default {
    display: none; 
}

#pageContentWrapper.show { 
    display: table; 
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: black; 
    font-family: 'Cloister Black';
}

#pageContentWrapperCell {
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

#pageContent_headingsWrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -75px;
    text-align: center;
    border: red 1px solid;
}

.pageContent_headerBox {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 2px #CCCCCC solid;
    color: black;
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.pageContent_headerBox_selected {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 2px white solid;
    color: white;
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.pageContent_headerBox_label {
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 18pt; 
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.pageContent_headerBox_price {
    color: inherit;
    font-size: 14pt;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#pageContent_title {
    width: 100%; 
    text-align: center; 
}

#pageContent_content {
    padding: 10px; 
    display: block; 
    min-height: 500px; 
    width: 75%; 
    margin: 15px auto; 
    background-color: white; 
    color: black; 
    font-family: 'Cloister Black';
    font-size: 14pt;
    text-align: center; 
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#pageContent_content p {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.pageContent_text {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

**CSS for small viewport:**

```
#pageContent_wrapper.show {
     margin-top: 30px;  
 }

#pageContent_headingsWrapper {
    height: 100px; 
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width: 100%
    text-align: center; 
    overflow: auto;  
}

#pageContent_headings {
    min-width: 250px;
    border: 1px green solid;
}

.pageContent_headerBox {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 2px #CCCCCC solid;
    color: black;
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
 }

.pageContent_headerBox_selected {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 2px white solid;
    color: white;
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Can you put that into jsfiddle with some sample content? I'm not sure where your content should go in order to replicate the problem.

Comment: I apologize. pageContent_headings is where I am putting the headings content that is the concern for this issue. In it I have some DIVs that are about 100px by 150px. I have them horizontally aligned in one row in there.

Comment: I don't see any problems when I tested it. Are you sure there were no other conflicts in your script which caused the extra space? Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/1hafdgh3/

Answer (score -1):

Instead of width:100% use width:auto